# ¿Como avisar de novedades en una web?

Tags: rss

soy nuevo en programación web y por motivos académicos diseñe una página web para un profesor, que trata de un sitio para alojar las notas para ciertos alumnos que cursan la materia, pero me dijo que si era posible avisar a los alumnos cuando se hagan cambios en la página, es decir, se suban notas o se informen actividades o información destacada, entonces como podría hacerlo? revise sobre RSS pero los alumnos tendrían que seguir el rss del contenido y bajar lectores en caso de no tener firefox pero quisiera una manera mas sencilla, pensé en algún tipo de formulario para suscriptores con una base de datos y para luego enviar un correo a todos los destinos, en realidad no se cual método usar, que me sugieren, NO quiero me den código solo que me orienten...

Comment: Personalmente usaría una lista de correo...o un SMS por teléfono.

Comment: La pregunta será cerrada pero te invito al chat donde podemos orientarte con este tipo de preguntas. Saludos. http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desarrollar la idea que tienes en mente no es una tarea sencilla. Requiere como bien has dicho esencialmente de una base de datos para alojar los alumnos y su información (como puede ser el correo electrónico), los exámenes que sube el profesor. Luego necesitas un servidor que haga ciertas tareas :

1. Conectarse a la base de datos
2. Responda a una petición en la que el profesor añade un examen
3. Una vez el examen se ha añadido, en la misma petición, busque todos los alumnos a los que les concierne ese examen (como ejemplo se me ocurre un campo en la bdd de alumno que se llame "curso") y utilizar un servicio de transporte `SMTP` para enviar un e-mail a cada alumno.

En mi humilde e ignorante opinión te recomiendo aprender `Node.js y Express` (basicamente porque es el único framework que he usado para el desarrollo de aplicaciones web) y se pueden hacer cosas como las que comentas. Ten en cuenta que lo que preguntas es muy general y puede dar lugar a diversas respuestas, pero pienso que mi recomendación es un buen punto de partida. Al menos lo ha sido para mí. Saludos! =)

Comment: Yo se usar smtp para enviar correos, en todo caso necesitaría solo almacenar los correos para luego usarlos cuando envié los mensajes de notificación. Pero de casualidad encontré Google Groups y creo que se puede hacer con eso, pues los usuarios interesados podrían entrar al grupo y ahí difundir la información, en general solo quiero avisar que subieron notas no tiene que ser nada elaborado, también creo que me sirve Google Calendar, pues para informar de futuros examenes publico el evento y los participantes del grupo tendrán sus avisos en sus correos, que opinas?

Comment: No he usado nunca estos servicios de google, alguna vez sí utilicé Google Fusion Tables que para almacenar información "no está mal". Como solución me parece correcto utilizar los servicios de google que comentas pero ten en cuenta que suelen tener limitaciones de uso, aunque creo que para tu caso es suficiente.